# configure django app to receive Apple App Store notification (refundNotification) and test it

Tags: python, ios, django, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I would like to configure my application to receive App Store Notifications in case of refund action.

First of all I have to configure my server to support App Transport Security (ATS). Let’s assume that I have a django application hosted on ingenx or apache server. How can I configure my server to support ATS protocol? Does supporting ATS Portocol means that I should use HTTPS protocol for my APIs? Or do I need to configure NSAppTransportSecurity in the middleware in Django settings?

**How would I support ATS in Django?**

After supporting ATS in Django, I would like to test the new configurations. Thus, I have to configure a subscription status URL for my app in App Store Connect. Then, I have to wait until the next app version is released on App store in order to activate the newly registered URL in the App Store Connect.

**How would I test, that I am receiving the REFUNDNotification without waiting until the next version to be released on App Store?**

Comment: Hey, have you found an answer to your question? Would be interested!